# Remove span using global variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a span with a global variable like this:

```
var $span = jQuery('<span></span');
jQuery($span).append('<img src="myimage.gif"/>'); 
jQuery($span).insertAfter('#username');
```

It works but I would like to remove the span in some part of my code. 
I try with:

```
$span.remove();
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you ever add the span to the dom? You also seem to be missing a `>`

Comment: Do you also add the element to the document? How?

Comment: Can you include the full code sample?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand why the people usually says that it's not usefull questions like this. I try to fix it an hour ago.

Comment: Try to recreate your problem on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *really* need to post the full code for questions like this. It makes it really difficult for people to help you if they can't see what you're doing in context.

That said, if `$span.remove()` does not remove the `<span>`, then plainly and simply `$span` is not referencing what you think it is. Either it's another element or it's undefined.

Where are you making it a "global" variable (bad idea by the way)? In javascript there really isn't such a thing as a true global variable -- they are only defined for for the context they are in. If the immediate context is your document (i.e. `<script>var myVar = 'foo';</script>`), that's for all intents and purposes a "global" variable, but anything else is a "local" variable.

Basically, use `console.log` or similar to introspect the value of `$span` in the place where you're trying to utilize it. If it's undefined (which my best guess is that it is), then figure out why it's not defined in the context your working in.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just use a script to do that. If the global variable is not a god idea for you, pls could you give me another way to do it.

Comment: I had a problem with the global variable because I had var $span = jQuery('<span></span'); inside a function. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

That's because $span doesn't exist in the DOM yet, thus it cannot be removed.

If you were to do this:

```
var $span = jQuery('<span></span'); // missing >

jQuery('body').append($span);

$span.remove();
```

That would both add it to the DOM, then remove it again.

Also as pointed out by Richard D, you're missing a `>` on your closing span tag.

Comment: Thanks to everybody but I can see the span. 

For example it works: 

    var $span = jQuery('<span></span');
    jQuery($span).append('<img src="myimage.gif"/>');
    jQuery($span).insertAfter('#username');

Comment: Thank you, It was more less that. I did the $span declaration inside a function :)